# Why can I not get application object in classic ASP when I add a .NET Wildcard mapping to directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, mapping, wildcard

We're migrating a site from classic asp to .NET. In the process, I need to use .NET authentication to secure the classic asp pages. This works great with wildcard mapping...unless the classic asp pages try to use something like the Application object.

I have tried adding an HTTPHandler to pass the request to the asp.dll, but to no avail.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have some of your old 'classic' asp pages within the same site as the .aspx pages?  We've done something similar here, but we wound up with two websites, one for the asp and one for the .net and did some session sharing to perform the authentication.

Comment: It is within the same site, but different virtual directories. I'm using web.configs in classic asp v-dir and the .net app, sharing machinekeys for auth. Like I said, this works great...unless I try to access the Application object in classic asp in that v-dir.

Comment: More research shows that the application object is available, it's commerce server 2002 that is causing me grief. There is a reference to a CS object in the application object that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on IIS7 using the integrated pipeline, I would say it would be highly fragile on IIS6 with wildcard mapping.